# Find $r\equiv 9^{137}*x^{51}+36^{1003}(\mod 7)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

For $x\equiv 1\mod 7$

I know that I can do $36^{1003}\equiv 1\mod 7$, but I do not understand how to go about the other part.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $9^3\equiv1\mod7$ and $36\equiv1\mod7$.

Comment: Thank you, I got that $9^{137}\equiv 4\mod 7$.